# Why the DataFrame does not update?

Tags: python, pandas, class, dataframe

I have this portfolio class and i want to create a function AddStockShares that checks if a stock exists and if so it adds the number of shares to the existing ones or else it throw an excemption. I wrote a query with iloc in order to get the value of shares that i want based on the given stock_ticker but when i add the new shares the stocks dataFrame does not update even though when i print the result in the function it is correct. Any suggestions?

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

class Portfolio(object):
"""description of class"""



array_of_stock_prices = []
array_of_stock_names = []
array_of_shares=[]
stocks = pd.DataFrame(np.column_stack([array_of_stock_prices, array_of_stock_names,array_of_shares]))

def __init__(self):
    print()

def AddStock(self, stock_ticker, stock_price,num_shares):
    if stock_ticker in self.array_of_stock_names:
        raise ValueError('Ticker already exists')
    else:
        self.array_of_stock_names.append(stock_ticker)

    self.array_of_stock_prices.append(stock_price)

    if(num_shares<0):
        raise ValueError('Number of shares cannot be negative,Check again')
    else:
        self.array_of_shares.append(num_shares)

    self.stocks = pd.DataFrame(np.column_stack([self.array_of_stock_names, self.array_of_stock_prices,self.array_of_shares]),
                          columns=['Ticker', 'Price','Shares'])

def BuyStockShares(self, stock_ticker, num_shares):
    if stock_ticker in self.array_of_stock_names:
        x=int(self.stocks.loc[self.stocks['Ticker']==stock_ticker,'Shares'])+num_shares
        print(x)
     else:
        raise ValueError('Stock does not exist.Add stock first')





por=Portfolio()
por.AddStock('AAPLE',100,200)
por.AddStock('SASA',500,10)
por.AddStock('xv',500,50)
por.BuyStockShares('xv',1000)
print(por.stocks)
```

Comment: "Checks if a stock exists and if so adds the number of shares" your code is the other way round, adding only if it doesn't exist and raising error if it already exists. Decide which you want. Do you want to append if it exists or if it doesn't exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update that row.

```
def BuyStockShares(self, stock_ticker, num_shares):
  if stock_ticker in self.array_of_stock_names:
    self.stocks.loc[self.stocks['Ticker']==stock_ticker,'Shares']=int(self.stocks.loc[self.stocks['Ticker']==stock_ticker,'Shares'])+num_shares
  else:
    raise ValueError('Stock does not exist.Add stock first')
```